# merge output in separate columns (comma separated)

Tags: shell

I have two outputs of a file (fetch using cut command).

One is

```
700316307503
700315522410
700317709443
```

and second is

```
ab
bc
cd
```

Both outputs have same number of rows.

I need to merge them or arrange them in a new file as following (comma separated new file)

```
700316307503,ab  
700315522410,bc
700317709443,cd
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using paste:

```
paste -d"," file1 file2 >file3
```